# Could first_open event be ~ x2 bigger then total app installs?

Tags: flutter, firebase, mobile, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

My Flutter app uses Firebase analytics. I encountered an issue when first_open event for the given period of time ~= 1.7k, but total app installs from Apple App Store and Google Play Store ~= 960.
I thought that maybe app update counts as a first_open event, but Firebase documentation says it doesn't.